# Connection to SignalR hub doesn't actually connect

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, websocket, signalr

I have been trying to implement SignalR into my ASP.NET Core Web API project. I have followed the bare minimum detaild on the docs to get it working. When I connect to the hub via Postman (and Insomnia) it says connected with Status Code 101 (I believe this is expected?). However, the override of the OnConnectedAsync method is never hit.

This is the hub:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace SignalRTest
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("method", "someone connected");
        }
    }
}
```

The Program.cs file is exactly the same as the template file just with `builder.Services.AddSignalR()` and `app.MapHub<ChatHub>("chat-hub")` added to it:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddSignalR();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();


app.MapControllers();

app.MapHub<ChatHub>("chat-hub");

app.Run();
```

I run the project and attempt a connection via postman with: wss://localhost:7090/chat-hub. The connection is successful with Status Code 101 Switching Protocols. So why is no message sent and the the breakpoint inside `OnConnectedAsync` in my hub not being hit when the example I have seen all have it working just from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SignalR protocol does more than a simple WebSocket connection. To properly test your SignalR hub, you should use a SignalR client.

```
    let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("https://localhost:7090/chat-hub")
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
    .build();

connection.start().then(function () {
    console.log("connected");
}).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});

connection.on("method", function (message) {
    console.log("Message received: " + message);
});
```

Refer following article for more information.
https://medium.com/@krishan-samarawickrama/building-a-real-time-application-with-asp-net-core-signalr-a-comprehensive-guide-874e975377c8

Comment: Added the equivalent of this to my react frontend and it works, thanks!

Comment: When you post answers with links to resources with which you have an affiliation, [you are expected](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) to disclose that affiliation in the post. Please [edit] your answer to include your affiliation. Otherwise your post may be deleted. Please see [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).